# Venting dryer into bathroom

Tags: bathroom, dryer, venting

My laundry has no roofspace access but shares an internal wall with the bathroom. The bathroom has a separate extractor fan on a different wall.

Is it a reasonable idea to vent the dryer into the bathroom, given there's no way to vent it elsewhere?

I figure it's better than no venting, and the windows and extractor fan in the bathroom should assist with moisture.

Or is this dumb and should I just get a condenser dryer?

Answer (score 2):

This should be ok so long as you have a type of dryer that does not require a vent. (IE not a gas dryer)

A condensing dryer will save you money in the long run as they consume much less energy.

Comment: Not "i.e." but "e.g.". A gas dryer is only one example of a vented dryer. And the OP has already said it's not condensing - so it requires a vent

Answer (score 1):

Not recommended but if you have no other choice then fine.  You may see condensation on tiles every time you use the dryer.

Comment: Cheers. Yeah, I would have far preferred to vent it outside but it's just not possible where the laundry is situated.